# I am trying to send some values (data) by form using AJAX but req.body is always empty or value undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, ejs

I am trying to send some values (data) by form using AJAX but req.body is always empty or value undefined.

```
app.post('/add', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {  
    console.log(req.body.email1);
    console.log(req.body.name1);
    console.log(req.body);
    //res.render(req.body.message);
    res.redirect('/todo');
});
```

Comment: Can you share your client-side code please? How you send this ajax request?

Comment: this is the code, thank you a lot  https://jsfiddle.net/amine_detter/t88uwkcg/

Comment: ok, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `json` parser instead of the urlencoded one.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.post('/add', bodyParser.json(), function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.email1);
    console.log(req.body.name1);
    console.log(req.body);
    //res.render(req.body.message);
    res.redirect('/todo');
});
```

You probably send `JSON` data by your `AJAX` call, and that's why the urlencoded parser can not parse the body. More info: https://www.quora.com/What-exactly-does-body-parser-do-with-express-js-and-why-do-I-need-it

**UPDATE**

As you send your post data as `multipart/form-data`, you'll need `multer` to parse this in `node.js`

```
var multer = require('multer')
var upload = multer();

app.post('/add', upload.array(), function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use req.param('email1') insted of req.body

Comment: @amine_detter can you put your code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [codepen](https://codepen.io/pen/)

Comment: @nayeri this is my code, thank you a lot https://jsfiddle.net/amine_detter/t88uwkcg/

Answer (score 0):

//this on client side...

```
<script>
        $(document.forms['formName']).on('submit', function(){
            var form = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                url: "/add",
                method: "POST",
                data: form.serialize(),
                statusCode: {
                    200: function(){
                        window.location.href = "/todo"
                    },
                    400: function(jqXHR){
                       //display errors
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    </script>
```

//and on server side

```
app.post('/add', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body.email1);
    console.log(req.body.name1);
    console.log(req.body);
    res.status(200);
});
```

befor all you need to connect

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

hope this help you

and if you need, a form view

```
<form name = "formName">
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <label for="email1">Enter email</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name = "email1" id="email1" placeholder = "Enter email">
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <label for="name1">Enter name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name1" id="name1" placeholder="Enter name">
    </fieldset>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you but is not working.  the url change to http://localhost:3000/todo?email1=aaaa&name1=bbbb

Comment: this helped you

 <script src = "/vendor/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>